# Solr / Zookeeper : "An exception was thrown while closing send thread"

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

I am trying Solr for the first time on RHEL 8 with Openjdk version "17.0.2".
I am following the tutorial https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/solr-tutorial.html. I get the warning:

```
WARN  - 2022-04-20 12:07:20.762; org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn; An exception was thrown while closing send thread for session 0x10003e1057e0003. => EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x10003e1057e0003, likely server has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:77)
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x10003e1057e0003, likely server has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:77) ~[zookeeper-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350) ~[zookeeper-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1275) ~[zookeeper-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
```

This should be a straight forward tutorial. Do you know what I am missing?

Here is tutorial from the start:

```
[solr@abc294837 ~]$ ./bin/solr start -e cloud

Welcome to the SolrCloud example!

This interactive session will help you launch a SolrCloud cluster on your local workstation.
To begin, how many Solr nodes would you like to run in your local cluster? (specify 1-4 nodes) [2]:

Ok, let's start up 2 Solr nodes for your example SolrCloud cluster.
Please enter the port for node1 [8983]:

Please enter the port for node2 [7574]:

Solr home directory /opt/solr/example/cloud/node1/solr already exists.
/opt/solr/example/cloud/node2 already exists.

Starting up Solr on port 8983 using command:
"/opt/solr/bin/solr" start -cloud -p 8983 -s "/opt/solr/example/cloud/node1/solr"

Waiting up to 180 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [\]
Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=50226). Happy searching!

Starting up Solr on port 7574 using command:
"/opt/solr/bin/solr" start -cloud -p 7574 -s "/opt/solr/example/cloud/node2/solr" -z localhost:2181

Waiting up to 180 seconds to see Solr running on port 7574 [-]
Started Solr server on port 7574 (pid=50417). Happy searching!
                                                                                                                          INFO  - 2022-04-20 12:07:20.502; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; Waiting for client to connect to ZooKeeper
INFO  - 2022-04-20 12:07:20.553; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; zkClient has connected
INFO  - 2022-04-20 12:07:20.556; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; Client is connected to ZooKeeper
INFO  - 2022-04-20 12:07:20.631; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader; Updated live nodes from ZooKeeper... (0) -> (2)
INFO  - 2022-04-20 12:07:20.737; org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ZkClientClusterStateProvider; Cluster at localhost:2181 ready
WARN  - 2022-04-20 12:07:20.762; org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn; An exception was thrown while closing send thread for session 0x10003e1057e0003. => EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x10003e1057e0003, likely server has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:77)
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x10003e1057e0003, likely server has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:77) ~[zookeeper-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350) ~[zookeeper-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1275) ~[zookeeper-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]

Now let's create a new collection for indexing documents in your 2-node cluster.
Please provide a name for your new collection: [gettingstarted]
´´´
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not missing anything, this is Zookeeper falsely warning about a socket connection being closed.

[EDIT] : This has been fixed in Solr versions 8.11.2, and 9.0.0 (Zookeeper versions 3.6.4, 3.7.1, 3.8.1, 3.9.0).

---

We can see in this [commit](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/commit/11c07921c15e2fb7692375327b53f26a583b77ca#diff-9657d4a14708c9ec1df56fd01581a442e10ef70cae39c7223d4f979b0ae54263R1234) that the exception is caught and expected (comment says `closing so this is expected`), yet it is now reported as a warning and a stack trace is logged, although this is not an error per se. So you can consider this message a debug message (as it was before that commit).

See for reference this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-15968), caused by this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-4376), and this [pull request](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/pull/1856) for the fix.

We can still make Zookeeper quiet from Solr/log4j config, by changing the level of its logger from "warn" to "error" :

*solr/solr/server/resources/log4j2-console.xml*

```
<AsyncLogger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="ERROR"/>
```

Comment: "Zookeeper falsely warning" I see this is being thrown in the `catch` block why do you think it's false?

Comment: @Vishrant Because it happens in the condition block `if (closing) { ... }`. In this situation, the exception is not really an exception as it is part of the [`closing`](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zookeeper/ClientCnxn.java#L189-L195) process (ie. it is intended and thus the exception to be expected), so there is no reason to _warn_ about this, and the log level should have remained as it were before (debug).

Comment: I also got this issue with AWS EMR 6.9 where ZK version is 3.5.10. @EricLavault - Referring to the ticket - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-4376 looks like it was put in DEBUG before but someone changed it to WARN. Maybe this ticket is old (and duplicate) and the community closed a newer ticket already and fixed it as you've mentioned, and nobody cared to mark this ticket duplicate and closed it. Regardless, it's definitely fixed in the master - https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zookeeper/ClientCnxn.java :)